# Intersecting row values from many R dataframes and calculate averages of the corresponding values

Tags: r, dataframe

Below is the example:

```
df1 <- data.frame("names" = c('John','Peter','Jolie'), "value1" = c(21, 24, 26), "value2" = c(20, 23, 32))
df2 <- data.frame("names" = c('Sam','John','Jolie'), "value1" = c(35, 11, 10), "value2" = c(10, 28, 27))
df3 <- data.frame("names" = c('Louis','Jolie','John'), "value1" = c(42, 74, 26), "value2" = c(26, 53, 54))
df4 <- data.frame("names" = c('Ale','John','Jolie'), "value1" = c(61, 34, 76), "value2" = c(28, 63, 38))
df5 <- data.frame("names" = c('John','Jolie','peter'), "value1" = c(11, 84, 86), "value2" = c(50, 13, 68))

intersect_names <- Reduce(intersect, list(df1$names,df2$names,df3$names,df4$names,df5$names))
```

Using the `reduce` and `intersect` command, I can get the intersection of all the names. But, I want the corresponding `mean` of `value1` and `value2` for each of the `names` in the dataframes.

Expected Output `dataframe`:

```
 names   Value1 Value2
 John    20.6   43
 Jolie   54     32.6
```

For ex: The value `20.6` was obtained by taking `mean(c(21,11,26,34,11))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a list of dataframes, extract the rows for `intersect_names` and take `mean` for each `name`.

```
list_df <- mget(paste0('df', 1:5))
intersect_names <- Reduce(intersect, lapply(list_df, `[[`, 'names'))

aggregate(.~names, do.call(rbind, lapply(list_df, function(x) 
                           x[x$names %in% intersect_names, ])), mean)
```

---

The same using `tidyverse` functions :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_df(list_df, ~.x %>% filter(names %in% intersect_names)) %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = mean))

#  names value1 value2
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 John    20.6   43  
#2 Jolie   54     32.6
```

Comment: This solution works fine for the problem I asked. However, If some of the values are negative, and if I want to consider the absolute values and then take the average. How to modify the code? Any suggestions, please?

Comment: You can use an anonymous function in `aggregate` i.e . `aggregate(.~names, do.call(rbind, lapply(list_df, function(x) x[x$names %in% intersect_names, ])), function(x) abs(mean(x)))`